# Error when using a custom filter to filter results returned by Accumulo

Tags: java, hadoop, accumulo

I wrote a very simple custom filter to filter results returned by Accumulo. This is the filter that I wrote

```
public class MyFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(Key key, Value val) {
        Long page = 1L;
        Integer limit = 25;

        if(key.getColumnQualifier().getBytes().equals("Class".getBytes()) && val.get().equals("1".getBytes())) {
            if(page == 1) {
                return true;
            }
            limit--;
            if(limit == 1L) {
                page++;
                limit = 25;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I added this filter to Accumulo's scanner like this

```
Set<Range> ranges = new HashSet<>();
IteratorSetting iter = new IteratorSetting(15, "MyFilter", MyFilter.class);
myScanner.addScanIterator(iter);
Iterator<Entry<Key, Value>> kys = myScanner.iterator();
while(kys.hasNext()) { // This is line 335 in com.latize.ulysses3.service.AccumuloPivotTable.getRows
    Entry<Key, Value> e = kys.next();
    ranges.add(Range.exact(e.getKey().getRow()));
}
```

But whenever I try to run this piece of code, I get this stacktrace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.AccumuloServerException: Error on server accumulo.tablet.2:9997
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ScannerIterator.hasNext(ScannerIterator.java:161)
        at com.latize.ulysses3.service.AccumuloPivotTable.getRows(AccumuloPivotTable.java:335)
        at com.latize.ulysses3.webservice.DataVault.getFilteredRows(DataVault.java:950)
        at com.latize.ulysses3.webservice.DataVault$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getFilteredRows(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:280)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:234)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:221)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invokePropagateNotFound(SynchronousDispatcher.java:217)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:224)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:62)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.marmotta.platform.core.servlet.MarmottaResourceFilter$LMFFilterChain.doFilter(MarmottaResourceFilter.java:189)
        at org.apache.marmotta.platform.core.filters.ModuleResourceFilter.doFilter(ModuleResourceFilter.java:169)
        at org.apache.marmotta.platform.core.filters.ModuleResourceFilter$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.marmotta.platform.core.servlet.MarmottaResourceFilter$LMFFilterChain.doFilter(MarmottaResourceFilter.java:184)
        at com.latize.ulysses.platform.core.filters.ClickJackFilter.doFilter(ClickJackFilter.java:105)
        at com.latize.ulysses.platform.core.filters.ClickJackFilter$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.marmotta.platform.core.servlet.MarmottaResourceFilter$LMFFilterChain.doFilter(MarmottaResourceFilter.java:184)
        at com.latize.ulysses.platform.core.filters.SessionTimeoutCookieFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeoutCookieFilter.java:125)
        at com.latize.ulysses.platform.core.filters.SessionTimeoutCookieFilter$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.marmotta.platform.core.servlet.MarmottaResourceFilter$LMFFilterChain.doFilter(MarmottaResourceFilter.java:184)
        at org.apache.marmotta.platform.core.filters.MarmottaServerNameFilter.doFilter(MarmottaServerNameFilter.java:104)
        at org.apache.marmotta.platform.core.servlet.MarmottaResourceFilter$LMFFilterChain.doFilter(MarmottaResourceFilter.java:184)
        at com.latize.ulysses.platform.core.filters.UlyssesTemplatingFilter.doFilter(UlyssesTemplatingFilter.java:178)
        at com.latize.ulysses.platform.core.filters.UlyssesTemplatingFilter$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.marmotta.platform.core.servlet.MarmottaResourceFilter$LMFFilterChain.doFilter(MarmottaResourceFilter.java:184)
        at org.apache.marmotta.platform.core.filters.TemplatingFilter.doFilter(TemplatingFilter.java:176)
        at org.apache.marmotta.platform.core.filters.TemplatingFilter$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.marmotta.platform.core.servlet.MarmottaResourceFilter$LMFFilterChain.doFilter(MarmottaResourceFilter.java:184)
        at org.apache.marmotta.platform.security.filters.MarmottaAccessControlFilter.doFilter(MarmottaAccessControlFilter.java:142)
        at org.apache.marmotta.platform.security.filters.MarmottaAccessControlFilter$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.marmotta.platform.core.servlet.MarmottaResourceFilter$LMFFilterChain.doFilter(MarmottaResourceFilter.java:184)
        at org.apache.marmotta.platform.user.filters.MarmottaAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(MarmottaAuthenticationFilter.java:228)
        at org.apache.marmotta.platform.user.filters.MarmottaAuthenticationFilter$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.marmotta.platform.core.servlet.MarmottaResourceFilter$LMFFilterChain.doFilter(MarmottaResourceFilter.java:184)
        at org.apache.marmotta.platform.core.servlet.MarmottaResourceFilter.doFilter(MarmottaResourceFilter.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.marmotta.platform.core.servlet.MarmottaPreStartupFilter.doFilter(MarmottaPreStartupFilter.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:169)
        at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.marmotta.platform.core.servlet.MarmottaOptionsFilter.doFilter(MarmottaOptionsFilter.java:83)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.AccumuloServerException: Error on server accumulo.tablet.2:9997
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ThriftScanner.scan(ThriftScanner.java:293)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ScannerIterator$Reader.run(ScannerIterator.java:80)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ScannerIterator.hasNext(ScannerIterator.java:151)
        ... 69 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing startScan
        at org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:111)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:71)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.tabletserver.thrift.TabletClientService$Client.recv_startScan(TabletClientService.java:232)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.tabletserver.thrift.TabletClientService$Client.startScan(TabletClientService.java:208)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ThriftScanner.scan(ThriftScanner.java:410)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.ThriftScanner.scan(ThriftScanner.java:285)
        ... 71 more
```

accumulo.tablet.2:9997 is the domain name of the machine that runs one of my tablet servers. The configuration is fine because other functions work properly. The port is up too. Can someone tell me why am I getting that error? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Beware, the equals method doesn't work on byte arrays (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499560/how-to-compare-the-java-byte-array).  Accumulo uses Hadoop's WritableComparator.compareBytes method instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use filter properly you have to add them to the accumulo classpath, typically by deploying the .jar file where the iterator is defined on each node of your system in `$ACCUMULO_HOME/lib` or `$ACCUMULO_HOME/lib/ext`. For a deeper understanding of iterators I recommend the very good [documentation of accumulo](http://accumulo.apache.org/1.7/accumulo_user_manual.html#_iterators).

For an easy deployment I'd like to suggest the use of [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/), [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/puppet/what-is-puppet) or [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/). If this is to much of an effort for your project a simple shell script will do as well. You may find the [cluster shell cssh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cssh) very helpfull for administration issues as well! Be aware that you do **NOT** need any restart of accumulo after the deployment in the `ext` folder, however it is necessary for the `lib` folder.

Comment: If there are quite a few nodes on your cluster, then do you have to add the filter to each and every node manually? Is there a way to set Accumulo's classpath to a HDFS location so that all nodes can access it without me having to manually deploy them on each and every node.

Comment: The thing is that I have an application that queries a bunch of tables in Accumulo. This application (web based) uses Accumulo's Java API to query the cluster.  The application itself does not run on any machine that hosts any of the tablet servers. If I would need to explicitly deploy the filters to each and every node in my cluster, then I would also have to add it to my application's classpath. Seems to be a hassle to me.

Comment: I added some more details in my answer. If you want to access accumulo directly from your webapp you habe to add the dependencies, thats for sure. If you have to keep the webapp slim you might want to add a simple rest server in your cluster the web app is communicating with. Even though this would add some effort...

Comment: Just a clarification: placing a jar in `$ACCUMULO_HOME/lib` *does* require a restart. `$ACCUMULO_HOME/lib/ext` does not.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification

Comment: Well Matthias, your initial answer did help. I am able to run my filter. But I have another question and I am not sure if this thread is the correct place to ask it. Is it possible for the filter to return the total number of results the filter will return without me having to iterate through the result set to get the count? I was thinking if some sort of pagination was possible.

Comment: @thisisshantzz it would be great if you can add another question to SO. Please try to clarify your goal, it seems to me that filter are no longer the right tool for the things you want. you may have to go to classic iterators or combiners of accumulo

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue. I was getting a ClassNotFound exception when I checked the tserver's logs. It would seem I need to add the class to Accumulo's classpath. But if I want to get these filtered results as part of an application rather than run it from the terminal, how would I go about doing it? It is possible that I would not be able to add the filter to Accumulo's classpath.