# java.util.Arrays.equals() with limited length

Tags: java, arrays, containers

I need to compare elements of two byte[] arrays but only up to fixed length.
For whole arrays I use `java.util.Arrays.equals()`. Of course I can copy sub-ranges (`Arrays.copyOf()`) but I'd like not to do so. I am also sure there should be standard way to do so without new utility method implementation.

What I need formally is something like:

```
java.util.Arrays.equals(byte[] a, byte [] b, int length)
```

Any point to something well known? I don't see widely used approach.

Again about what is asked to prevent false answers:
 - Array equals with limit on length.
 - I HAVE manual implementation but I'd like to replace it with something standard.
 - I don't want any copy.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can always copy the source of `Arrays.equals` and amend as required.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ByteBuffer provides something similar to what @meriton proposed but can work with primitives.
Here is illustrative code:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {

        byte [] a1 = {0, 1, 0, 1};
        byte [] a2 = {0, 0, 1, 0};

        boolean eq = ByteBuffer.wrap(a1,0,3).equals(ByteBuffer.wrap(a2,1,3));
        System.out.println("equal: " + eq);
    }
}
```

Properties of @meriton answer:

- Result is collection with full power of using them.
- Actually it is somewhat copy (but not full).
- Requires references, primitives cannot be wrapped in this way.

This answer specials.

- Backend array is NOT CHANGED in any way. `ByteBuffer.array()` returns
  reference to original array (could be disadvantage, could be
  advantage).
- It works with primitives.

Answer (score 9):

This feature is added in Java 9. Given array a and array b, you would do:

```
//with char array
    Arrays.compare(a, startIndex_A, endIndex_A, b, startIndex_B, endIndex_B);

//with byte, short, int, long arrays
    Arrays.compareUnsigned(a, startIndex_A, endIndex_A, b, startIndex_B, endIndex_B);
```

Answer (score 7):

You could based your method throught the source code of Arrays.equals.

```
public static boolean equals(byte[] a, byte[] a2, int length) {
        if (a==a2)
            return true;
        if (a==null || a2==null)
            return false;

        for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
            if (a[i] != a2[i])
                return false;

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You could do:

```
Arrays.asList(a).subList(0,n).equals(Arrays.asList(b).subList(0,n))
```

Comment: No problem with exception, this solution is right what I actually searched for. My +1 also.

Comment: For `int a[] = { 1 };`, `int b[] = { 2, 3, 4 };` and `int n = 2;` it throws `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: toIndex = 2`, according to [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)  `subList()` throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException - for an illegal endpoint index value (fromIndex < 0 || toIndex > size || fromIndex > toIndex)`.

Comment: Really nice answer deserving its +5... but does not work for primitives so is not solution for this answer. Looks like I found the solution based on your point :) - will check and post.

Answer (score 0):

Why not trivially implement it yourself?

```
public static void firstNEqual(byte[] a, byte[] b, int n) {
    assert a.length >= n && b.length >= n;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if(a[i] != b[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

What makes you think there should be a utility method built in? What if my condition is `a[1:4] == b[0:3]`? Is that more readable as `Arrays.subrangesEqual(a, b, 1, 0, 3)`, or as an explicit for loop:

```
for(int i = 1, j = 0, count = 0; count < 3; count++, i++, j++)
    if(a[i] != b[j])
        return false;
return true;
```

Comment: You probably want to add some null checks

Comment: @assylias: Why? I'd say it's pretty obvious from the method that you have to pass non-null parameters - why not just let the `NullPointerException`s be thrown further down?

Comment: to be consistent with `Arrays.equals`.

Comment: Eric, please look my answer - this is what I was searching for. Why not manual? Key answer is efficiency - compare by element leads to things like every element index range checking and so on.

Comment: "What makes you think there should be a utility method built in?" Because in c you have strncmp() and memcmp(s1,s2, size_t n). It seems trivial that Java should have it too.

Comment: "What makes you think there should be a utility method built in?" There is one for plenty of other Array utilities, including copying ranges of arrays that, in fact, are similar to your `subrangesEqual` hypothetical function. I, personally wouldn't say that one "should" be built in but no harm in asking.