# How can I check two Object-Arrays for Equality in JUnit?

Tags: java, junit, equals, junit4, assert

I have a JAVA class *NoName* whose objects have the method *getProperties()*. This method returns an Array of *Property*. 
When I now have two instances of *NoName*, how can I use *assertEquals* to check whether both instances' *Property*-Arrays are the same?

`_assertEquals(inst.getProperties(), ance.getProrties())_` won't do the job, because it's deprecated.

And since the *NoName* class is a library class I cannot overwrite *equals()* (which seems to be the usual solution for this kind of problem, as far as I read until now).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing arrays in JUnit assertions, concise built-in way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228161/comparing-arrays-in-junit-assertions-concise-built-in-way)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
assertThat(ob1.getProperties(), 
    IsArrayContainingInOrder.contains(obj2.getProperties));
```

This is using a Hamcrest Matcher which I believe to be a preferable method to doing asserts since the output on failure is much more descriptive.

There is also an `IsArrayContainingInAnyOrder` if order does not matter.

[IsArrayContainingInAnyOrder](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.2.1/hamcrest-library-1.2.1-javadoc.jar!/org/hamcrest/collection/IsArrayContainingInAnyOrder.html)

Comment: Is this a special library I have to include into my workspace? Because then it won't do the job.

Comment: It is in the Hamcrest library. A small portion of Hamcrest Matchers comes in the JUnit jar, but the rest are in the Hamcrest-core and Hamcrest-all jars. I recommend that you list these two jars earlier in your class-path than the JUnit jar to ensure you get these Matchers before the default JUnit matchers.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're talking about comparing an internal structure of an object, you can either override the `equals` method for the `NoName` class, and inside that compare the array of properties for both objects. But then, you'll need to take care of the `hashCode` method too.

Or, you can simply create a helper method `hasSameProperties(NoName obj)` in the `NoName` class, and make that method return a boolean flag after comparing the property arrays of both the objects. Then in JUnit, you can simply use the `assertTrue` method.

Comment: I cannot write into the `NoName` class. It is part of a library.

Answer (score 0):

```
Property[] one = inst.getProperties(), two = ance.getProperties();
assertEquals(one.length, two.length);
for (int i=0; i<one.length; i++) assertEquals("index #" + i, one[i], two[i]);
```

That provides a basic scrub.  If you're worried about some other edge conditions (e.g., like the array might be null, or that the array is allowed to have a different order as long as all the same elements are in each), then some extra work will be required (e.g., null check, a sort if `Property` implements `Comparable`).

Comment: Although I think Hamcrest is a better option here, if this mechanism is used a "reason" should be provided: `assertEquals("index #" + i, one[i], two[i]);` otherwise the provided error message will be useless.

Comment: @John B: excellent point, I will make that adjustment to the answer. re Hamcrest, yes, but: that's a question of engineering that depends on scale - of organization doing the testing, of testing for this code, etc.  If this is a quickie (e.g., junit to aid in small scale debugging), it's probably more hassle to sort getting the path to the library correct than any additional info would be worth.

Comment: Ah, the beauty of Maven. I always just think "Oh, I'll just add that dependency."

Answer (score 0):

Hamcrest 1.3 uses a slightly different syntax, some examples:

```
import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsArrayContainingInOrder.arrayContaining;

...

@Test
public void inOrder1() {
    assertThat(new String[]{"foo", "bar"}, arrayContaining(equalTo("foo"), equalTo("bar")));
}

@Test(expected =  AssertionError.class)
public void inOrder2() {
    assertThat(new String[]{"bar", "foo"}, arrayContaining(equalTo("foo"), equalTo("bar")));
    // Expected: ["foo", "bar"]
    //      but: item 0: was "bar"
}

@Test(expected =  AssertionError.class)
public void inOrder3() {
    assertThat(new String[]{"foo", "bar", "lux"}, arrayContaining(equalTo("foo"), equalTo("bar")));
    // Expected: ["foo", "bar"] in any order
    //      but: Not matched: "lux"
}

@Test(expected =  AssertionError.class)
public void inOrder4() {
    assertThat(new String[]{"foo", "bar"}, arrayContaining(equalTo("foo"), equalTo("bar"), equalTo("lux")));
    // Expected: ["foo", "bar", "lux"] in any order
    //      but: No item matched: "lux" in ["foo", "bar"]
}
```