# How to compare two Linked Lists correctly in JUnit?

Tags: java, junit, assert

I have the following sentence:

```
assertArrayEquals(Arrays.asList(df.sort("State", new SortDescending())).toArray(),Arrays.asList("[WV, WV, WI, WA, VA, TX, SD, PA, OH, ND, NC, NC, MB, MA, KS, FL, DE]").toArray());
```

The return of the function is a List< Object > and it contains:

```
[WV, WV, WI, WA, VA, TX, SD, PA, OH, ND, NC, NC, MB, MA, KS, FL, DE]
```

The error is:

```
Expected :java.util.LinkedList<[WV, WV, WI, WA, VA, TX, SD, PA, OH, ND, NC, NC, MB, MA, KS, FL, DE]>
Actual   :java.lang.String<[WV, WV, WI, WA, VA, TX, SD, PA, OH, ND, NC, NC, MB, MA, KS, FL, DE]>
```

Why i don't pass the test when I compare these two lists?

Comment: I didn't double check, but `is` might imply identity, i.e., they're the same object, which is obviously not true.  Try an `assertEquals` comparison.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing arrays in JUnit assertions, concise built-in way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228161/comparing-arrays-in-junit-assertions-concise-built-in-way)

Comment: In Java, you CANNOT compare two different arrays with "==".  Similarly, in  JUnit you cannot compare two arrays with "is()".  You must use [assertArrayEquals](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html).

Comment: `Arrays.asList("[WV, WV, …, DE]")` is a List containing exactly one element.  You probably meant to write `Arrays.asList("WV", "WV", "WI", "WA", /*etc.*/, "DE")`.  There should be no `[` or `]` in the code.

Comment: I edited the question... I tried to do it with assertArrayEquals but it continues wrong...

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Since there were a few issues going on, I wasn’t sure if it was the answer, but now I’m convinced it is.

Comment: @VGR Upvoted as promised

Answer (score 1):

In Java, `"` characters specify a String value.  Not a List.  Just a single String value.

This:

```
"[WV, WV, WI, WA, VA, TX, SD, PA, OH, ND, NC, NC, MB, MA, KS, FL, DE]"
```

is not a List.  It’s a single String object, whose value may happen to look like a List, but it’s not a List.  It is in double-quotes (`"`), therefore it is a single String object.

This:

```
Arrays.asList("[WV, WV, WI, WA, VA, TX, SD, PA, OH, ND, NC, NC, MB, MA, KS, FL, DE]")
```

create a List which contains *one element.*  It is a `List<String>` with a size of one.

`Arrays.asList` does not attempt to parse Strings in any way.  You cannot specify a List of items inside a single String value.

What you probably meant to write was this:

```
Arrays.asList("WV", "WV", "WI", "WA", "VA", "TX", "SD", "PA", "OH", "ND", "NC", "NC", "MB", "MA", "KS", "FL", "DE")
```

Notice that are no `[` or `]` characters.  The List is comprised of individual String values, each specified as a separate argument to Arrays.asList.

You might find it easier to just compare the Lists directly:

```
Assert.assertEquals("Checking for correctly sorted list.",
    Arrays.asList("WV", "WV", "WI", "WA", "VA", "TX", "SD", "PA", "OH", "ND", "NC", "NC", "MB", "MA", "KS", "FL", "DE"),
    Arrays.asList(df.sort("State", new SortDescending())));
```