# The junit `isEqualTo` method doesn't pass the test even though the values ​are the same

Tags: java, spring, junit

The JUnit `isEqualTo` method doesn't pass the test even though the values ​​are the same.

```
expected: "[Floor{id=507, sbmFloorName='Rail', sbmFloorId='0', sbmFloorBase='-3', sbmFloorGroup='0', sbmFileName='choryangStn_110_220114_Rail_0.sbm'},
    Floor{id=508, sbmFloorName='Platform', sbmFloorId='1', sbmFloorBase='-2', sbmFloorGroup='1', sbmFileName='choryangStn_110_220114_Platform_1.sbm'},
    Floor{id=509, sbmFloorName='B1F', sbmFloorId='2', sbmFloorBase='-1', sbmFloorGroup='2', sbmFileName='choryangStn_110_220114_B1F_2.sbm'},
    Floor{id=510, sbmFloorName='1F', sbmFloorId='3', sbmFloorBase='1', sbmFloorGroup='3', sbmFileName='choryangStn_110_220114_1F_3.sbm'}] (PersistentBag@6c79a7c1)"

 but was: "[Floor{id=507, sbmFloorName='Rail', sbmFloorId='0', sbmFloorBase='-3', sbmFloorGroup='0', sbmFileName='choryangStn_110_220114_Rail_0.sbm'},
    Floor{id=508, sbmFloorName='Platform', sbmFloorId='1', sbmFloorBase='-2', sbmFloorGroup='1', sbmFileName='choryangStn_110_220114_Platform_1.sbm'},
    Floor{id=509, sbmFloorName='B1F', sbmFloorId='2', sbmFloorBase='-1', sbmFloorGroup='2', sbmFileName='choryangStn_110_220114_B1F_2.sbm'},
    Floor{id=510, sbmFloorName='1F', sbmFloorId='3', sbmFloorBase='1', sbmFloorGroup='3', sbmFileName='choryangStn_110_220114_1F_3.sbm'}] (PersistentBag@1a16583d)"
```

Even though the values ​​are all the same as shown below, the test does not pass. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Have a look at the `equals` implementations of `PersistentBag` and whatever classes you have put in it. To be honest I'm not sure what this is trying to say: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/collection/PersistentBag.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Comment: I’m guessing you have an Assert that is something like `Assert.equals(array1, array2)`.   This would be effectively performing  `array1.equals(array2)`.   Please edit your question to show whether this is what your code looks like - and if it is, have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777257/equals-vs-arrays-equals-in-java    And for a solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228161/comparing-arrays-in-junit-assertions-concise-built-in-way

Comment: Could you post your `Floor` and test case ?